# Unity, MoveTowards works weird

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, position, move

Allright, I have gameObjects with tag "Enemy" and I collect them like this:

```
 enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
```

After that, I am trying to move the first "Enemy":

```
     int newPositionX;
     int newPositionY;
     bool targetReached = false;
     int moveSpeed = 1;
     void Update()
     {
     if (!targetReached)
         {
             newPositionX = Mathf.FloorToInt(enemies[0].transform.position.x)-1;
             newPositionY = Mathf.FloorToInt(enemies[0].transform.position.y);
             enemies[0].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(enemies[0].transform.position,
                 new Vector3(newPositionX, newPositionY), moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
             targetReached = true;
             }
             if (Vector3.Distance(enemies[0].transform.position, new Vector3(
                 newPositionX, newPositionY)) < 0.1f)
             {
                 targetReached = false;
             }
         }
```

But an "Enemy" is not making any moves. I can edit that if I remove the:

```
 targetReached = true;
```

the "Enemy" is moving but there's no way I can stop it. That makes me think that to make sth moving MoveTowards function should be called permanently in the Update?

Answer (score 0):

MoveTowards returns a vector that moves the gameobject one step in the direction of the target.

Also, I am not sure about this, but looking at your code, the if statement that sets the targetReached to false only runs if the targetReached is already false, so you may want to put that out of the if (!targetReached) statement

Answer (score -1):

You probably had the idea that Unity is a complete game engine.

It isn't.

The most basic of things, like tweening and movement aren't provided in the ways just about every other game engine on earth provides them.

So you need to download and setup a plugins and add-ons to get basic functionality.

Search for tweening engines for Unity, and read up about them, as you'll need to understand them and how they incorporate themselves into Unity for the next time you meet missing basics of Unity.